# How do I simulate Visual Studio application window activation?

Tags: wpf, window

I'm trying to do something similar to what visual studio does with it's windows.  I have a similar tabbed interface and I have added the ability to undock a tab into a separate window.  The functionality I'm trying to get is where a user activates one of the windows of the application, all of the application windows should be brought to the top.  My first thought was to override the OnActivated Window method where I would activate all of the other application windows.  However, this is insufficient because that ends up bringing all of the other windows on top of the window I just activated (since OnActivated is called after the window is activated).  I can't activate it last in this event because that would fire the activated event again (infinite loop).  It would be nice if there was an OnActivating event that was call before the window was activated.

Has anyone else done this?

This doesn't work because it brings the other windows on top of the one just activated.

```
public partial class EditorWindow : Window
{
  public event EventHandler ActivateOtherWindows;

  protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
  {
    if(ActivateOtherWindows != null)
    {
      ActivateOtherWindows(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    base.OnActivated(e);
  }  
}
```